# using dictionary when trying to use optimizer.apply_gradients

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow2.0

I think the error is because my "para" is a dictionary, anyone knows any quick fix for this while preserving para as a dict?

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(para)
    Loss = CLoss(para)
grads = tape.gradient(Loss, para)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,para))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Which library is your code using and what error are you getting?